# mysql:get a static column with given values and another column with id if value exist

Tags: mysql, select

Is this possible in MySQL?

Let's say i have a table:
ID, Name

Now, i want to run a query to see if these names exists "John,James,Bill". Assuming only the name James exists in database (ID:23, Name:James) i wish to see this result:

```
ID    | Name
------------
null  | John
  23  | James
null  | Bill
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need an *outer join* between your table and some table that contains the list of names for which you wish to search (you can either create such a table before running your query, or materialise such a table within the query using `UNION` as shown below).  Learn about [SQL joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html).

```
SELECT * FROM my_table NATURAL RIGHT JOIN (
  SELECT 'John' AS Name UNION ALL SELECT 'James' UNION ALL SELECT 'Bill'
) t
```

See it on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7fe97/1/0).

Comment: exactly! thank you for the answer eggyal! (there a small typo in query -last character "t")

Comment: @Sharky: That's not a typo, it's a dummy alias for the materialised table.

Comment: worked like a charm. plus i get to learn something new. thank you eggyal

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `IN()` comparison function to check `WHERE Name IN ('John', 'James', 'Bill')`. If you wish to return a result that shows `ID` of matches you can use:

```
SELECT b.ID, a.Name
FROM sparkles a
LEFT JOIN (SELECT ID, Name FROM sparkles WHERE Name IN ('John', 'James', 'Bill')) b ON b.ID = a.ID
```

Comment: Doesn't return the desired results.  [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9925a/1/0).

Comment: @eggyal Yes it does. It found a match. See [update](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9925a/2). I dropped 'James'.

Comment: But the desired resultset contains three records, one for each person being searched.

Comment: @eggyal Ah, I see now. I took it as those names were records and to only show matched.